# Reading multiple csv files for TensorFlow

Tags: python, csv, tensorflow, input

I'm trying to implement a LSTM network using TensorFlow 2 but I'm having problems with taking input. My dataset is in the form of multiple CSV files I have more than 100 CSV files in a directory that I want to read and load them in python. they contain customer's information. each file has 50 columns and many rows so they don't fit in memory!
I have read many documentation and I know the best way is to use generator function and chunks so i tried but still have problems... I will show part of a CSV file.

[part of a CSV](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uAdJX.jpg)

How do i take these multiple CSVs as input?

Comment: Your question has a doble side: one is hardware, the other is software. For the second I don't have any idea, because you know your job, so if you need TensorFlow, let's use it.  But TensorFlow needs memory, more memory! 16GB it's a starting point: how much memory your hardware has?

Comment: I certainly am not a TensorFlow expert, I believe you can save your model using model.save(). Then, you can either load a saved model to train it with new data, or you can continue training your model.

Comment: How many lines one CSV does have? You might consider [`tf.data.experimental.make_csv_dataset`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/experimental/make_csv_dataset)